# Number of steps to empty an egg basket

Tags: algorithms

A basket contains $n$ eggs. We eat $1$ egg and the remaining doubles. We eat $2$, and the remaining doubles. We eat $4$ and the remaining doubles and so on.

We need to determine if for any $n$, will the basket be completely emptied? If so, how many steps are required to do so? The eating and doubling of remaining eggs count as $2$ separate steps.

I tried to run this for some $n$ and observed that the number of steps was always equal to $2n$. I'm not able to start with the proof.

```
eggs = int(input("Enter number of eggs: "))
steps = 0
power = 0

while eggs != 0:
    eggs -= 2**power
    power += 1
    steps += 1
    eggs *= 2
    steps += 1
    

print(f"Steps = {steps}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Let $E_k$ denote the number of eggs after $k\ge 0$ steps, starting with $E_0 = n$. Then,
$$
\begin{split}
E_{n+1} &= 2\left(E_n - 2^n\right) \\
E_{n+1} - 2E_n &= -2^{n+1}
\end{split}
$$
Do you know how to solve such a recurrence? You can use either generating functions or solve it directly...

Comment: Note that what's considered one step here is two steps in the problem description. But mathematically the step definition here makes more sense.